# Change the font size of quick launch headings in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to change the font size of the Headings of the quick launch in sharepoint 2010.
How to do this please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the elements with for example Firebug (in Firefox) and add a css to your masterpage to modify the correct classes

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the headers like Lists and Libraries, they have a class of "static menu-item" and have a base style of:

```
.s4-ql ul.root > li > .menu-item, .s4-qlheader {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0;
    color: #0072BC;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

So you'd either need to override this by creating your own stylesheet and attaching it to the masterpage or using the option to link an additional stylesheet to your site to override the styles.